# How to open a command line terminal and execute some commands inside robot framework testcase?

Tags: robotframework

I Want to do the following steps:

open a terminal of the same ubuntu machine from where my Robot testcase is running and execute some commands.

written a Robot framework testcase as shown below:

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Telnet


*** Testcases ***

testcase1
    open connection          127.0.0.1
    write                    gnome terminal
    write                    ifconfig -a eth0
```

But its throws "Errno 111 - connection refused" error.

Kindly guide me if anybody have idea on this.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to open a terminal window, or do you just need to execute commands? And when you say "... where my test is running", do you literally mean that, or are you trying to run the ifconfig command on the machine you're telnet'ing into?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't actually need to open a terminal window, robot has a [Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html) library that lets you run external commands via the [Run process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process) keyword. For example:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Process

*** Test cases ***
| Example
| | Run process | ifconfig | -a | eth0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I want. But If we execute "scapy" in the place of "ifconfig", its not working. Simply its hanging. no error. Any clue please?

Comment: @rcubefather: I have no idea. I don't know what scapy does. Perhaps the arguments you're giving it is making it run interactively.

Comment: Thanks... let me try scapy and update. just to tell, scapy is a open-source, python based packet generation tool. if we execute "scapy" command, we will get interactive shell.

Comment: @rcubefather: you can't run an interactive shell from within robot. That's why it hangs when you call that command.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is twofold

In most (all including Ubuntu) Linux distributions Telnet is closed by default. This is probably true for your case as well. 
You could run the telnet server on the Ubuntu machine, or even configure it to run on startup (There are many threads on how to do that).

But as other people said before - running Telnet on your local machine is probably not really what you want. You can use the Process library to run processes on your local host,and even the built in library has a few keywords for that.

Answer (score -1):

Create .bat file and write your commands in that. If your .bat file located in other folder then use cd commands and then your required commands

Example of bat file like
cd C:\robotFramework\runner
java    abc.class
Use following syntex

Run    xyz.bat    : for this use Library     OperatingSystem
Or
Run Process    xyz.bat   : for this use Library     Process

Comment: the OP is about Ubuntu linux - a bat file (windows) is not going to solve the problem.